# how to write a condition for all elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I have a list

```
a={no,no,no,no};
```

now I can want to an `If` so that if all elements of the above list are "yes" it does something for example printing sth, I tried

```
a[[All]]=yes;

If[a[[All]]==yes, Print["that's OK"]];
```

but I know my command is wrong, any idea?

Comment: You should be using `===` instead of `==` here, since you are comparing symbols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but for your specific example, the following works:

```
If[Union@a == {yes}, Print["that's OK"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my mean, but I didn't think `Union` works in this case

Answer (score 13):

You could also try `AllTrue`:

```
If[AllTrue[a, # == yes &], Print["that's OK"]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is more comprehensible

Answer (score 8):

An even more expressive approach (in my opinion at least) is to use [`ContainsOnly`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsOnly.html):

```
If[ContainsOnly[{yes}]@a, Print["that's OK"]];
(* that's OK *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also `Apply` an old-fashioned logical `And`:

```
If[And @@ (# === yes & /@ a), Print["that's OK"]]
```